# Geo Location - PHP Array sorting

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I've got a bunch of records for business locations in a directory. About 4,500 actually.

I have a bit of a problem with speed at the moment, for 2 reasons. When the user loads the page they are asked to input their postcode.

When they do so the page will reload and fetch all the businesses, foreach loop around them and calculate the distance between the postcode entered and the postcode stored for the business. After the initial loop is completed (which includes a SQL query). The records are then sorted by the distance away from the user.

It results in a tremendously slow page load and is pretty unusable at the moment.

What would your suggestions be for speeding this up? Considering you cannot cache the results easily since each user's postcode will be different.

Live source - http://discoversolar.co.uk/directory/type/mcs-installer/

Comment: For speeding your calculations we have to see some code.

Comment: Also which part takes long? The SQL query (or are that even queries?) or the PHP part?

Comment: Why don't you simply return ~50 results and sort them, only querying for the next 50 results when the user requests them?

Comment: Because you don't know what 50 results to grab until you calculate the distance from the postcode entered.

Comment: @David Well actually a preview of results could be given by taking the first letter of the postcode and restricting results based on that thus reducing your dataset. The first letter or so still covers a huge area.

Comment: Is it really necessary to loop through all businesses, do you need the whole list? If you could restrict the search to businesses inside a certain radius, you could make your query much faster [see this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19762/3576).

Answer (score 2):

You need to avoid the PHP forloop by moving distance calculations into the database query:
1. Ensure you have coordinates in the database for business locations.
2. Get the coordinates for the users postcode.
3. Use curvature of the earth formula as follows.

```
<?php
$postcode_latitude = x;
$postcode_longitude = y;

$sql = "
    select 
        *,
        6371.04 * acos(cos(pi()/2-radians(90-latitude)) * cos(pi()/2-radians(90-".$postcode_latitude.")) * cos(radians(longitude)-radians(".$postcode_longitude.")) + sin(pi()/2-radians(90-latitude)) * sin(pi()/2-radians(90-".$postcode_latitude."))) as distance
    from 
        my_table
    having 
        distance < 50
    order by 
        distance 
    limit 0,10";
?>
```

This will work fine on your 4,500 business locations. From experience on [sletoH.com](http://www.sletoh.com), approach 100,000 DB records and the SQL will slow down. At this stage you will need to avoid calculating distance for all DB records by adding a SQL where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to look for `query optimization`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/6137168

Comment: I don't think it's the query itself that is slowing the page load down, it's the foreach loops and the distance calcs.

Comment: sometime if you not having index in your database table, it is taking too much time for query execution.

Comment: i don't think? Did you measure queries? Or it's just a suggestion that  this is not loops?

Comment: I do have a large query above the loop to fetch them.

Comment: But that query when tested returns in 234ms with 4676 rows.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to minimize the dataset too loop over. Here in Sweden our postcodes are organized in a way that if the code is close to another code then they're close to each other geographically as well.

You can maybe select the 100 closest datapoints and do your thing on that.

Even if your algo is O(n²) then minimizing your set with 4 500 will issue a big "performance" hit (not technically, but the end user will get the page much faster).

Comment: You can actually see the page in question here if you like ... http://discoversolar.co.uk/directory/type/mcs-installer/

Answer (score 0):

I have a mapping [demo](http://daviestrachan.zxq.net/maps/stationmap8.php) It which uses geocoding for location and a database of uk staions(2,757 records). It is quite fast and can be adapted for postcodes.

Comment: I spent a little time optimising queries and the loop a little and managed to speed up the page loads fair bit. Which has now made my pages useable.